# Can't trap (Ctrl^C) in my bash script

Tags: bash

I don't know why I can't trap Ctrl^C in this simple script.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for number in $(seq 10); do
  echo -n "."
  sleep 2
done

function finish() {
  echo "bye."
}

trap finish SIGINT
```

I've tried using `INT` instead of `SIGINT`, without success.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer inspired by edit to OP. Please don't kill me...

---

Order in scripting is pretty important. First off, you need to put the function first. You also need to put the trap before the loop. Something like this should work well:

```
#!/bin/bash

function finish() {
        echo "bye bye!"
}

trap finish SIGINT

for number in $(seq 10); do
        echo "TODO: Insert work here..."
        # Insert work to do here.
done
```

Comment: can you provide another SIGs for other keyboard shortcuts? such as CTRL-R and CTRL-X.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/743662/12574