# run command before script exits

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have some hardware I'm testing with a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
tshwctl --setdio=65
for i in $(seq 0 1000)
do
 ./adc1
sleep 1
done
tshwctl --clrdio=65
```

If I press Ctrl+C before it is finished the loop, pin 65 will not be unset.
(I can unset it later sure)
is there a way to execute a process after pressing `Ctrl+C`?
as in: is there a way for the script to execute `tshwctl --clsdio=65`  before the script exits when ctrl+C is pressed?

Comment: Try putting it in a SIGINT trap - see for example [Can't trap (Ctrl^C) in my bash script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524525/cant-trap-ctrlc-in-my-bash-script)

Comment: Read `man bash`, the `trap` subcommand is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use after the shebang `#!/bin/bash`:

```
trap 'tshwctl --clsdio=65 &>/dev/null' 1 2 3 15
```

or you can remove `--clsdio` from the bottom script and use:

```
trap 'tshwctl --clsdio=65 &>/dev/null' EXIT
```

to run the command in all `EXIT` use cases

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SignalTrap